# How can I submit form on button click when using preventDefault()?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I'm using jQuery's `.preventDefault()` to prevent form submit when users clicks the [ENTER] key. The problem is that it also stops the form submitting when I click the submit button.

I see there are many threads on Stackoverflow in regards of `.preventDefault()`, but none of them addresses my problem.

Here's the code I'm currently working on.

```
// Part of my form
<form id="subscription_order_form" class=""  method="post" action="some_url"> 
  <button id="btn_order" type="submit">Order</button>
</form>

// Prevent the form to be submitted on ENTER
$('#subscription_order_form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Controll data
$('#btn_order').click(function(){
  checkMandatoryFields();
});


// Check mandatory fields before subitting:
function checkMandatoryFields(e){

  // Code for testing here

  // Set "error" message and abort submission
  if(msg.length > 0) {
    // Do something
  } else {

    //submit or trigger is not recognized as functions
    $('#subscription_order_form').submit(); //.trigger('submit');

  }
}
```

Can anyone please tell my what he code for submitting the form on button click is?

Comment: I'm puzzled why you would WANT to prevent users from submitting via the "enter" key. It's a common convenience.

Comment: Really? Then I must be one of the few that always clicks the submit button. In any case, I have form fields that can be changed and depending on the input value I do javascript calculations.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Trigger the submit event on the DOM Node, not a jQuery Object.

```
$('#subscription_order_form')[0].submit();
```

or

```
$('#subscription_order_form').get(0).submit();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("subscription_order_form").submit();
```

This bypasses the jQuery bound event allowing the form to submit normally.

Comment: May I know what is the `[0]` do in this line of code `$('#subscription_order_form').get(0).submit();`?

Comment: @Anu it’s effectively document.getElementById(‘subscription_order_form’).submit(). jQuery select methods return array-like objects, so [0] would give you the form node

Answer (score 6):

You need to use

```
$(this).parents('form').submit()
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the submit button to a normal button and handle submitting in its onClick event.

As far as I know, there is no way to tell if the form was submitted by Enter Key or the submit button.

Comment: I tested that, but the form will still not submit using `$('#subscription_order_form').submit();`

Comment: That's because submit() only raises the onSubmit Event, which doesn't do much in your code. You have to call the action URL with the Form data yourself, i.e. via $.ajax

Answer (score 4):

Replace this :

```
$('#subscription_order_form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

with this:

```
$('#subscription_order_form').on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.which===13) e.preventDefault();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kqqbx/1/)

That will prevent the form from submitting when Enter key is pressed as it prevents the default action of the key, but the form will submit normally on click.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. See updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kqqbx/3/ The form is submitted on clicked, even when the control fails.

Comment: @Steven - I see what you're trying to do now, and it's probably something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kqqbx/6/)-----

Comment: That almost works. The only problem is that [ENTER] is not workign in input text fields: http://jsfiddle.net/kqqbx/9/

Comment: And removing the `e.which===13` for input text fields will submit the form on ENTER.

Comment: @Steven - the `enter` key has a default action in a text field, and it is to submit the form. Either the enter key works and submits the form, or it does'nt work at all, there's no inbetween as that is what the key does??? If the problem is to avoid the enter key from submitting the form only when pressed on the submit button, look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kqqbx/10/)

Comment: I solved it by setting `preventDefault` on submit, and then change button type from `submit` to `button` and then use @kevin-b's solution for submitting the form. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first `e.preventDefault();` it's not a Jquery element, it's a method of javascript, now what it's true it's if you add this method you avoid the submit the event, now what you could do it's send the form by ajax something like this

```
$('#subscription_order_form').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
     url: $(this).attr('action'),
     data : $(this).serialize(),
     success : function (data){

      }
   });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```