# How to submit a specific form if multiple forms are present in one page using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have two forms.

```
<form name="frm1" action="someurl" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="btn1" class="buttons" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and

```
<form name="frm2">
  <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I need to submit form "frm1" on click of "btn2" of form "frm2".

Comment: So what are the problems you are having?

Comment: I am not able to submit frm2 on click of btn2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you would say

`<input type="submit" name="btn1" id="btn1" value="Submit"/>`

```
 $("#btn1").click(function(){  
  $("#frm1").submit();
}
```

and

`<input type="submit" name="btn2" id="btn2" value="Submit"/>`

```
 $("#btn2").click(function(){  
  $("#frm1").submit();
}
```

Comment: don't forget to add the closing parenthesis and semicolon

Answer (score 49):

```
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

The `form` attribute specifies the `id` of the form that the button will submit.

Comment: How is this not the best solution?  Using jQuery events doesn't seem like the easier way compared to this.

Comment: Yes unquestionably the best. Why using JQUERY when native HTML can do it ?

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<form name="frm1" action="someurl" method="post" id="frm1">
<input type="submit" name="btn1" class="buttons" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<input type="submit" name="btn2" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Submit"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function formSubmit()
{
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

consider the HTML:

```
    <form id="target" action="destination.html">
    <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
    <div id="other">
    ....
    </div>
```

The event handler can be bound to the form:

```
    $('#target').submit(function() {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    return false;
    });
```

Click function:

```
    $('#other').click(function() {
    $('#target').submit();
    });
```

Here is the link have a look:
[How can I submit form on button click when using preventDefault()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581462/how-can-i-submit-form-on-button-click-when-using-preventdefault)

Comment: Try passing the form 2 id in your button click function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to submit the first form before the second one:

```
$('form[name=frm2]').submit(function() {
    var form1 = $('form[name=frm1]');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form1.attr('action'),
        data: form1.serialize(),
        async: false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually avoid the .submit() function as i almost always have to do something more with response that .submit() would allow me to do.

Thus, a non .submit option where you SUBMIT buttons would have to be changed to normal buttons.

```
$('.btn2').bind('click', function(){

    var form1Data = $('#frm1').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'someurl',
        type : 'post',
        datatype : 'json',
        data : form1Data,
        success : function(json) {
            sumbitForm2();
        }
    });
});

function submitForm2() {

    var form2Data = $('#frm2').serialize(); 
    $.ajax({
        url : 'urlToSumbitForm1',
        type : 'post',
        datatype : 'json',
        data : form2Data,
        success : function(json) {
            //do something if you need to
        }
    });
}
```