# How can I submit a sepecific form when I have multiple forms on my page?

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to submit a form. Like this it is working very well:

```
   <form>
    <input name="name" value="somebody"><br>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="Submit"  name="submit" >Submit</button>
   </form>  

<script>
    $(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $form = $(this);
            submit($form);  
            });

        function submit($form){
            ...do something....
        }
</script>
```

But I have multiple forms on my page, so I am trying to do something like this:

```
      <form name="myform">
        <input name="name" value="somebody"><br>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="Submit"  name="submit" >Submit</button>
       </form>  

    <script>
        $(document).on('submit','myform',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $form = $(this);
                submit($form);  
                });

            function submit($form){
              $.ajax('action.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function(result) {
                $('#result').html(result);
              }
           });
       }
    </script>
```

But this is unfortunately not working. Do you know why?

Comment: Just give it a unique id or class and then $form = $(this); would become $form = $('#formId');

Comment: @DanWeber Ok, I will test it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @DanWeber Unfortunately with your solution my function `submit($form)` didn't work anymore

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129916/how-to-submit-a-specific-form-if-multiple-forms-are-present-in-one-page-using-jq

Comment: @DanWeber Yes, I did already, but that didn't work out for my function

Comment: Let me throw some code up for you.

Comment: You could also specify an `action` attribute for each form element. It may help to find a website online that has multiple forms on the page, and have a look at the page source (specifically, the markup for each form element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. You could also have different functions for each form submission.

```js
function submit($form, action) {
  alert("Submitting form");

  $.ajax(action, {
    method: 'POST',
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
      $('#result').html(result);
    }
  })
}

// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {

  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    alert("Submitting form 1");

    submit($("#frm1"), 'action1.php');
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    alert("Submitting form 2");

    submit($("#frm2"), 'action2.php');
    $("#frm1").submit();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm1" name="frm1">
  <input name="name" value="somebody">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="Submit">Submit Form 1</button>
</form>

<br>
<br>

<form id="frm2" name="frm2">
  <input name="name2" value="somebody else">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="btn2" name="btn2" value="Submit">Submit Form 2</button>
</form>
```